# Space Between Nav

Tags: html, css, nav

How do I make a nice header/nav section?

This is my code:

```css
body {
   margin: 0px;
}

.container {
  width: auto;
  height: 1920px;
  background-color: #514367;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #647551;
  top: 0px;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 24px 0px 5px 30px;
}

nav li {
   margin-right: 40px;
   list-style: none;
   text-decoration: none;
   display: inline;
}

nav li a {
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <link href="css/Main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Talkody - Design Services</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <!-- Menu start -->
         <header>
            <nav>
               <ul>
                  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="about/index.html">About</a></li>
                  <li><a href="portfolio/index.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                  <li><a href="contact/index.html">Contact</a></li>
               </ul>
            </nav>
         </header>
         <!-- Menu end -->
         </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

So what I want. I want the text a little bit more in the middle. Wait!, let's tell it in a another way. You see the 'StackExchange' navbar above?; Well, that's what I want. I want the text on the right (but centered in the middle area) and then a logo on the left (but also centered in the middle area).

I'm trying to improve my acknowledge in HTML5. So I started working with the nav and header function.

Comment: bootstrap navbars do the exact same thing and they are also responsive for mobile view. you can check them out at http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/

Comment: It's helpful but I want to explore the HTML5 world. I don't like copying things etc. Is there another way instead of Bootstrap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A great HTML5/CSS3 positioning solution is CSS Flexbox.

To begin using this, add `display:flex` to your `<ul>`. Then it's internal items can be positioned a variety of ways with properties either on the flex container (the `<ul>`) or on the flex children (the `<li>`).

To keep your `<ul>` and it's children from extending too wide (like the stack overflow nav does) I've given it a set width of 80%, then centered it inside of the `<nav>` using flexbox as well.

Flexbox is a really versatile tool for positioning, you can read a little more about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
body {
   margin: 0px;
}

.container {
  width: auto;
  height: 1920px;
  background-color: #514367;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #647551;
  top: 0px;
}

nav {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  }

ul {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:80%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  }

#logo {
  margin-right:auto;
  }
  
nav ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 24px 0px 5px 30px;
}

nav li {
   margin-right: 40px;
   list-style: none;
   text-decoration: none;
   display: inline;
}

nav li a {
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <link href="css/Main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Talkody - Design Services</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <!-- Menu start -->
         <header>
            <nav>
               <ul>
                  <li id="logo"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="about/index.html">About</a></li>
                  <li><a href="portfolio/index.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                  <li><a href="contact/index.html">Contact</a></li>
               </ul>
            </nav>
         </header>
         <!-- Menu end -->
         </div>
   </body>
</html>
```